# Is UImage.AsPNG() thread safe?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uikit

Is `UImage.AsPNG()`  thread safe? When using `UImage.AsPNG()` in Xamarin.iOS 6.3.5.43 from a separate thread, I'm getting a `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException`.
From the Apple docs I cannot see that this method is required to be executed on the main thread.
I did not get this warning in the 6.2 branch.

Comment: Nothing in UIKit is thread safe.

Comment: @H2CO3 "Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe": http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is thread-safe and it has been fixed in the [recently released Xamarin.iOS 6.2.7.](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_6/xamarin.ios_6.2#Xamarin.iOS_6.2.7)

The problem was that we had a discussion with Apple engineers about thread-safe API, and we made a mistake when we went through the information they'd given us. A bit more information is available in the [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12472).

Answer (score 1):

> From the Apple docs I cannot see that this method is required to be executed on the main thread

Apple don't specify per-method thread safety for `UIKit`. Rather, [this disclaimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955-CH1-SW1) is given in the main framework reference:

> Note: For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your application’s user interface in any way.

Going back to your original problem - `UIKitThreadAccessException` is thrown on debug builds by MonoTouch. It's intended to serve as a checker/debug tool to make sure you're not doing UIKit stuff on a secondary thread.

Because from iOS 4 certain UIKit methods (mainly those involving drawing to a graphics context) became thread safe there's a whitelist of methods that MonoTouch won't throw this exception for, which is available in the MonoTouch documentation.

I couldn't say whether `UIImage.AsPNG()` is or isn't thread safe...I don't think it is, but if I'm wrong - or you want to risk it - you can pass the `--disable-thread-check` flag to disable MonoTouch's automatic UIKit background thread checking. [This blog post](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2012/Sep-10.html) might be helpful.